# How to turn off real time protection in Windows defender fort removable media

Tags: windows-10, security

I am using Windows 10 Home.  Is there a setting allowing me to turn off real time protection for USB flash drives without complicated registry manipulation?

Comment: As of W10-v2004 defender cannot be easily (registry edits no longer work) prevented from protecting the PC, one solution may be a 3rd party AV that allows this.

Comment: Can you not create a folder exclusion for the anticipated drive letter(s)?

Answer (score 0):

No. Windows Defender will scan your complete computer setup including removable devices. True for newest versions of Windows 10 including Home.

You can try top notch 3rd party AV but most of these enforce USB scanning as well.